How do I get past a code screen lock/Google lock after factory reset with USB and tablet
I can't get into my Motorola Moto G after a factory reset. It is number code screen-locked and Google-locked. I've tried using the emergency call from the start screen already.
I'm looking for help using a USB and tablet to get into my phone. I am open to any way to do it too.

Welcome. I've just heard about the "number code screen lock" after the factory reset. Did you mean a lock screen (which should have gone after the factory reset)? Is this device locked by Find My Device? For Google-lock/FRP, try How to bypass Factory Reset Protection (FRP) or "Verify your account" screen?

Assuming you were able to get in before, the same code or Google account will let you in again.  There is no other way.
